# File Transfer Ubuntu to Ubuntu by USB

Tags: 13.04, files, file-sharing

I have to share a file (40 GB) to another computer but, using DVDs and Flash Drives is too  hard. And I have a USB cable which I can plug into the two computers at same time.

Can I use it to transfer the file between two Ubuntu computers?

Comment: you want to transfer files anyway, or only via USB ?
p.s. I think that is possible again with high speed using network

Comment: so can i transfer file over usb , or create usb network ?

Comment: hm.. actually I don't know what usb network is, but I meant you can use simply LAN for doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the usbnet drivers and a host-host USB cable to do this. In [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room), the user [fossfreedom](https://askubuntu.com/users/14356/fossfreedom) gave me a good link about the ["usbnet" Driver Framework](http://www.linux-usb.org/usbnet/) .

I also saw a great cable and I will buy it.